# Pronunciation of the /h/ sound at the end of “yeah”

Tags: pronunciation

Do native speakers pronounce "h" when saying "yeah"?

Someone says yes, and someone says no.

Maybe it's not a standard question, but I am wondering. Maybe it is pronounced with aspiration?

Answer (score 10):

Standard English does not use the /h/ sound at the end of syllables, only at the beginning. (In fact, I have never heard a dialect with final /h/.) *Yeah* is pronounced “yĕ-uh” (/jɛə/ in IPA notation), with a diphthong or glide ending with the “uh” (/ə/) sound.

The {h} in the spelling is there to distinguish *yeah* from *yea*,  a now-archaic word for *yes* which is pronounced “yay” (/jeɪ/). The {h} indicates that the {a}, representing /ə/, is a distinct sound.

Comment: I know the French in general find it at least "difficult" to articulate an /h/ at the beginning of a word, but I can't begin to get my head around how it would even be *possible* to articulate /h/ at the end of a word.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Think of it is a **very** attenuated {ch}, as in German *ach*.

Comment: By the way, its /jɛə/ (or maybe /jæə/) in IPA, not /yɛə/

Comment: @aestrivex Of course you're right. That's what happens when you get lazy and cut-and-paste.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, try saying "behind", then say it again without the "ind".  It's strange for you because English doesn't allow final /h/, but plenty of languages do.